# Ubuntu 10.04 LDAP Replication

Tags: ldap, openldap

Ubuntu 10.04 LDAP Replication - please help

I was trying to setup [LDAP Replication](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/openldap-server.html#openldap-server-installation).

But I put the wrong IP address in the `consumer_sync.ldif` file and now I am trying to fix it but I am getting the following error;  please help me out!

```
jsmith@s2rweb2:/var/nfs$ sudo ldapadd -c -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f consumer_sync.ldif
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
modifying entry "cn=module{0},cn=config"
ldap_modify: Type or value exists (20)
    additional info: modify/add: olcModuleLoad: value #0 already exists

modifying entry "olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config"
ldap_modify: Type or value exists (20)
    additional info: modify/add: olcDbIndex: value #0 already exists
```

Comment: You are using the ldapadd command. It complains because you already have added those entries. You should use the ldapmodify command only containing your change of ip with the proper syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The consumer_sync.ldif you use try to add attributes even added in your directory, now you have to write the LDIF file that modify them. Don't know if it's possible, but perhaps you can try to modify config with Apache Directory Studio.

You must adapt this, it's just given "as is" without test.

```
# syncrepl specific indices
dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcSyncRepl
olcSyncRepl: rid=0 
 provider=ldap://Your new adress
 bindmethod=simple
 binddn= The Bind DN
 credentials= Your secret
 searchbase="dc=...,dc=..."
 logbase="cn=accesslog" 
 logfilter="(&(objectClass=auditWriteObject)(reqResult=0))"
 schemachecking=on 
 type=refreshAndPersist
 retry="60 +"
 syncdata=accesslog
-
replace: olcUpdateRef
olcUpdateRef: ldap://Your new adress
-
```